# "Could not load referenced assembly System.Core.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Caught a `BadImageFormatException` saying

> "Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

This is the error message that I get when I try to run my project. Can someone help me?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758588/system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-x-accessor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load a .net framework dll from a project running .net 1.1.  Either that or you have a mis-match in running a x86 app vs a 64 bit dll, or trying to run a x64 app against a 32 bit dll.

Check with architecture you are running, and the target framework of the application.